I got error, when I run ng serve with Angular CLI 16.1.8 and Node version (16.15.0)
I have been learning Angular for 2 weeks. I deleted the actual src file and paste the src file that contain source code of angular 16.1.8 and node 16.15.0   . I have also Angular CLI 16.1.8 and Node version (16.15.0)  but  I got error, when I run ng serve with Angular CLI 16.1.8 and Node version (16.15.0).
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/comp-accumulated/comp-accumulated.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(69:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/comp-cascade/comp-cascade.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(109:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
Code:
align-items: start
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/depart-memberdetail/depart-memberdetail.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(69:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
Code:
justify-content: start
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/dept-accumulated/dept-accumulated.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(69:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/emp-accumulated/emp-accumulated.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(69:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/rlt-accumulated/rlt-accumulated.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(69:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/section-groupby/section-groupby.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(69:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/subsec-groupby/subsec-groupby.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(69:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
./src/app/dialog/masters-popup/user-adddepartment/user-adddepartment.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(50:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
./src/app/dialog/scorecard/monthly-split/monthly-split.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(162:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
Code:
align-items: start
./src/app/masters/master-dashboard/company-params/company-params.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(33:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
Code:
justify-content: start
./src/app/module/bsc-review/bsc-review.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(450:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
align-items: end
./src/app/module/bsc-review/bsc-review.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
(451:3) from "autoprefixer" plugin: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead
Code:
justify-content: end
166 | }
167 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "19.0.0", ngImport: i0, type: ChartComponent, decorators: [{
168 |             type: Component,'
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:4:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'apexcharts' or its corresponding type declarations.
4 type ApexCharts = import("apexcharts");
~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:7:28 - error TS2693: 'ApexCharts' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
7         ApexCharts: typeof ApexCharts;
~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:11:45 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
11     readonly chart: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:12:51 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
12     readonly annotations: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:13:46 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
13     readonly colors: import("@angular/core").InputSignal<any[]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:14:50 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
14     readonly dataLabels: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:15:46 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
15     readonly series: import("@angular/core").InputSignal<ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries>;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:16:46 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
16     readonly stroke: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:19:47 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
19     readonly markers: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:20:46 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
20     readonly noData: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:21:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
21     readonly fill: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:22:47 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
22     readonly tooltip: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:23:51 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
23     readonly plotOptions: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:24:50 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
24     readonly responsive: import("@angular/core").InputSignal<ApexResponsive[]>;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:27:58 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
27     readonly forecastDataPoints: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:28:44 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
28     readonly grid: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:31:48 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
31     readonly subtitle: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:33:56 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InputSignal'.
33     readonly autoUpdateSeries: import("@angular/core").InputSignal;
~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:34:50 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/VSCP/Angular/project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'OutputEmitterRef'.
34     readonly chartReady: import("@angular/core").OutputEmitterRef<{
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:37:79 - error TS2694: Namespace 'globalThis' has no exported member 'ApexCharts'.
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:29:26 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'plotOptions' because it is a read-only property.
29                         [plotOptions]="piechart_status.plotOptions" [labels]="piechart_status.labels"
~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:29:70 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'labels' because it is a read-only property.
29                         [plotOptions]="piechart_status.plotOptions" [labels]="piechart_status.labels"
~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:30:26 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'colors' because it is a read-only property.
30                         [colors]="piechart_status.colors">
~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:50:33 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'series' because it is a read-only property.
50                     <apx-chart [series]="task_donut_chart.series" [chart]="task_donut_chart.chart"
~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:50:68 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'chart' because it is a read-only property.
50                     <apx-chart [series]="task_donut_chart.series" [chart]="task_donut_chart.chart"
~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:51:26 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'labels' because it is a read-only property.
51                         [labels]="task_donut_chart.labels" [colors]="task_donut_chart.colors"
~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:51:61 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'colors' because it is a read-only property.
51                         [labels]="task_donut_chart.labels" [colors]="task_donut_chart.colors"
~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:52:26 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'plotOptions' because it is a read-only property.
52                         [plotOptions]="task_donut_chart.plotOptions" [legend]="task_donut_chart.legend"
~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:52:71 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'legend' because it is a read-only property.
52                         [plotOptions]="task_donut_chart.plotOptions" [legend]="task_donut_chart.legend"
~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.html:53:26 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'dataLabels' because it is a read-only property.
53                         [dataLabels]="task_donut_chart.dataLabels">
~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/dialog/bcsreview_dialogs/actuals-details/actuals-details.component.ts:34:16
34   templateUrl: './actuals-details.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ActualsDetailsComponent.
Error: src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:123:61 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'series' because it is a read-only property.
123                                                 <apx-chart [series]="linechart.series" [chart]="linechart.chart"
~~~~~~
src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:20:16
20   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.
Error: src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:123:89 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'chart' because it is a read-only property.
123                                                 <apx-chart [series]="linechart.series" [chart]="linechart.chart"
~~~~~
src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:20:16
20   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.
Error: src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:124:54 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'xaxis' because it is a read-only property.
124                                                     [xaxis]="linechart.xaxis" [title]="linechart.title"
~~~~~
src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:20:16
20   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.
                                                      ~~~~~

src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:20:16
20   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.
Error: src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:125:54 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'stroke' because it is a read-only property.
125                                                     [stroke]="linechart.stroke" [dataLabels]="linechart.dataLabels">                                                         ~~~~~~
src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:20:16
20   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.
Error: src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:125:82 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'dataLabels' because it is a read-only property.
125                                                     [stroke]="linechart.stroke" [dataLabels]="linechart.dataLabels">                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/module/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:20:16
20   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.
Error: src/app/module/orgchart/orgchart.component.ts:11:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3-org-chart' or its corresponding type declarations.
11 import { OrgChart, State } from 'd3-org-chart';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: src/app/module/orgchart/orgchart.component.ts:73:34 - error TS7006: Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type.
73             .linkUpdate((d: any, i, arr) => {
~
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
× Failed to compile.

Please refrain from just posting a non-formatted error dump.  You need to explain what exactly you're doing and what steps you tried fixing it.  That said, did you look at this error? This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 19.0.0, which requires Angular version 17.2.0 or newer to work correctly. Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular. 163 | } 164 | /** @nocollapse  What Angular version are you using?

Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
